# How to prevent unwanted data to be created on production environment when running API functional tests as part of the post deployment tests

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, functional-testing, continuous-deployment

I am part of a project where we are working towards automated deployments on production environment. One of the items in that automated deployment process (framework yet to be chosen - probably would be Jenkins) would be to run API functional tests and UI automated tests to verify the deployment status and confirm if everything is working as expected.

The question is :
(1) Should such automated tests work on production environment ?
(2) If they should, how should situations be handled for API / UI tests which create data in the system which should not exist in production systems e.g. a job board application. Jobs created by such tests should not exist in the system as they would fudge job count and be taken by end users as actual job positions.

I would like to know how such situations should be handled in automated build delivery environments.

Answer (score 0):

You should not perform any testing on Production environment, other than functionality testing - e.g. making sure service is available and stable, able to receive requests, without actually polluting the production database - a lot of developers choose to add health check functionality in their API to be able to perform health checks on production.

You can also deploy to a staging environment first in order to run tests that need to input data into the database, if acceptance criteria is met, deploy to Prod. 
Staging of course should have a completely separate environment and database.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: If testing should not be done on **production**, how should it be ensured that all steps in the deployment were done ok, e.g. database migration script executed, new changes to storage mechanism e.g. moving image storage from file system on server to s3 etc. Health checks would only check for either server responding fine or maybe checking for a response from a health check api. These could be responding fine but a new deployment may be causing an error in one of the core apis of the application which were working previously. How is such a situation catered to ?

Comment: As mentioned above, after you have a given release (which has been thoroughly tested via Unit/BDD tests, performance, security, coverage & quality, etc) you need to deploy to a staging/testing environment first without real users / data and do your acceptance testing there (whether manual QA, automatic or both), only if those are met you go ahead and deploy to production (perhaps even to a portion of your user base first). You should not be finding functionality is not as expected after a production deployment, as you should ideally discover those issues on a testing environment.

Comment: I understand your point. But my question is still answered - how should it be ensured that all steps in the **production** deployment were done and none were missed ? That could only be done by verifying some functionality on **production** which I was thinking should be done via tests. Are you saying that no tests should be done on **production** and it should be assumed that all deployment steps were followed correctly ?

Comment: You need to create functional tests that are non polluting for production.
For example, your deployment job runs a DB script that creates a schema, instead of running some UI/API test that will pollute your DB, you can create a non polluting test that will just query to run those checks.
The point is to avoid any data in production which is not relevant for production.
I find this not necessary as Jenkins monitors exit codes. If my DB script has failed it will return a non-zero exit code and the build will fail.